# NG2 duplicate module name

Tags: angular, primeng

Using ng2 calendar module from PrimeNG [(link)](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)  and [open source calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar#development).

`import {CalendarModule} from "primeng/components/calendar/calendar";
 import {CalendarModule} from 'angular-calendar';`

How can I import both modules into mine?

Now TS says Duplicate identifier 'CalendarModule'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give an alias in typescript import.
Try

```
import { CalendarModule as c }  from "primeng/components/calendar/calendar";
```