# Duplicate identifier 'ModalModule' in ng2-modal and angular2-modal

Tags: angular

It might be a simple problem for some, but seems a big deal to me. 
I am using ng2-modal to show few Modal dialog boxes in my angular2 app. I want to use angular2-modal to show another family of popups. But when I use `import { ModalModule }` from both the packages together in common `shared.module.ts` file, it throws error for duplicate module. How can I rename ModalModule in any one of them? Else, how can I avoid this error?

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-modal';
import { ModalModule } from 'angular2-modal';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NG2 duplicate module name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393856/ng2-duplicate-module-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured we can give an alias to the second import class.

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-modal';
import { ModalModule as SecondModal } from 'angular2-modal';
```

This is super cool.